# Will someone share their thoughts on why these types of URL's would be searched?

Tags: security, url, code-injection

At least once a week while perusing logs I find a URL that looks like this:

`/static/jquery-file-upload/
/vendor/jquery-file-upload/`

Or something like this:

`/Trace.axd/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/sssp.pHp`

Does anyone know what this person is trying to do, and why?

Answer (score 1):

They're testing your site to see if you have code installed with known security vulnerabilities.

Jquery has a widget that allows users to upload images. But early versions had a vulnerability that allowed an attacker to upload arbitrary code files instead of images, and then execute the code files on the web server. A patch was developed in 2018 to fix this, but some sites may still have the old version of Jquery installed.

PHPUnit has several vulnerabilities that allow arbitrary code execution, because it will run code you send it using `eval()`. The protection is NEVER to put PHPUnit files in a place where an attacker can reach them directly via URL. In fact, I don't think there's any good reason to deploy PHPUnit files to your production site at all. PHPUnit is a tool to use in development and testing.

Update: The developer of PHPUnit agrees: https://thephp.cc/news/2020/02/phpunit-a-security-risk

Does your site have the exploitable code for either of these two vulnerabilities? That's what the attacker is checking. It costs them almost nothing to try this exploit on every website.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Turns out it was a pen test. Thanks again Bill!